# Get the Page ID from a campaign or adset

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to find the page ID connected to my campaign or adset (no matter which of them) but it's not clear to me how to find it.
I have the campaign ID and all the connected adset IDs so I can use both.

I tried using this doc https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign

What I tried is to get the page_id from the promoted_object but sometimes it has not the page_id in it.

Am I doing it wrong?
Which is the right way to get the page_id?

Answer (score 0):

1. create campaign
2. create adset (need campaign_id)
3. create creative,
   In this step, pageid will be added.

try to get creative and get page_id from it. 
hope this will be helpful.

[image: Using Graph API]

Comment: Can you give more details? as images or links?

Comment: steps are shown here:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/buying-api